# Putting .CSV data in HTML (Github-pages)

Tags: html, csv, github-pages

Here is my Publication.csv file:

```
"Name","Published"
"Study 1","1/1/2016"
"Study 2","1/2/2016"
```

And in my html file, I call it through:

```
<ul>
{% for date in site.data.Publication %}
<li>

    {{ "Name"."Name" }}-{{ "Name"."Published" }}

</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm using GH-pages, thus the "site.data" part. But it posts nothing. How do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're using [Jekyll functionalities](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) : liquid tag and [data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/).

Your data file must be in **_data/Publication.csv**, and your loop can look like this :

```
<ul>
{% for date in site.data.Publication %}
  <li>{{ date.Name" }}-{{ date.Published }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```